# Using generic as parameter in constructor Kotlin

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, constructor-overloading

I m using two constructor with different input types one as string and other as generic. The problem is while using Kotlin its only using the string constructor and ignores the generic

```
class DataResponse<T> {
    var isSuccess: Boolean = false
        private set
    var errorMessage: String? = null
    var data: T? = null

    constructor(success: Boolean, data: T) {
        this.isSuccess = success
        this.data = data
    }

    constructor(success: Boolean, errorMessage: String) {
        this.isSuccess = success
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage
    }
}
```

usage

```
    if (apiResponse.code() == 200) {
                    Observable.just(DataResponse<List<ResultDTO>>(true,
 apiResponse.body()?.resultList)) ---> **(error on this line forcing to convert it to string)**
                } else {
                    Observable.just(DataResponse(false, "Something went wrong"))
                }
```

Comment: Is there a reason for keeping both `isSuccess` and `errorMessage`? I'd just keep error message and change `isSuccess` to function or `val` returning true in case error is null. Maybe introduce static factory for invoking error/success constructors, I think it's a little confusing when you have 2 constructors that essentially change what your object represents. That would also fix the issue of constructor "clash" in case of `T` being a `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give named parameters in kotlin. That is if more than two constructors or functions with same name exists, we can explicitly specify the parameter as named one. Here I suggest to explicity mention the parameter `data`.

```
    if (apiResponse.code() == 200) {
        Observable.just(DataResponse<List<ResultDTO>>(true,data=
        apiResponse.body()?.resultList))
    } else {
        Observable.just(DataResponse(false, "Something went wrong"))
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently your `DataResponse` class represents two different things. One is an error message and the other one is actual data in case of success. `isSuccess` is redundant too because it is always `true` when data is non-null and always `false` if errorMessage is non-null.

I would change the design in the following way:

```
sealed class DataResponse

class SuccessResponse<T>(val data: T?)

class ErrorResponse(val errorMessage: String)
```

Now you have two separate classes, both having the same supertype `DataResponse`. This way you will always know what you are dealing with.

Usage:

```
when(dataResponse) {
    is SuccessResponse -> TODO("deal with data")
    is ErrorResponse -> TODO("deal with error")
}
```